# client command to list contracts results in stack overflow

Tags: node

tried out this command

./tezos-client list contracts

as shown in [Tezos Gitlab](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/api/cli-commands.html)

but it yields the following error:

> Fatal error: exception Stack overflow
>   Raised by primitive operation at file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1275, characters 17-21
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1311, characters 4-103
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1880, characters 12-72
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1209, characters 10-18
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1275, characters 17-21
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1311, characters 4-103
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1880, characters 12-72
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1209, characters 10-18
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1275, characters 17-21
>   Called from file "src/core/lwt.ml", line 1311, characters 4-103

etc etc etc.

Any idea why the command yields this error?

Comment: What commit is your repo synced  at ? Sounds suitable for filing a ticket on gitlab. Pls do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command is quite literally scanning the entire blockchain, looking for KT1 addresses that have contract code on them. Is this what you want? This seems like an incredibly useless command since you can't filter with it. You've probably exhausted some memory limits within the tezos-client by scanning the entire chain like this.

Maybe you want `list known contracts` instead? This will show you the KT1s of which your client is aware.